# Set width of a JLabel and add a tooltip when hovering

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` with unknown content and I have two things I want to do:

- I want to set a maximum or perhaps even static width of the label. And if the text is larger than the label it would somply shorten it, like this:

> Verylonglabel

becomes

> Veryl

Is it a bad idea to use static width on components in a gui? If that is the case, what is the alternative? Please give me advice!

- When you hover over the label I want a tooltip with the full length string to appear. So in our case, if i hover over the label that says "Veryl", a tooltip displaying "Verylonglabel" would appear. However, it should display a tooltip with the full length string even if it was not shortened.

Help with either of these is greatly appreciated.

So far I've just messed around a bit and tried things like this without sucess. It doesn't seem to care about the size at all.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Verylonglabel");     
label.setSize(15, 5);
```

Best regards, Goatcat

Comment: just put the label as width as long. if your content long from the label you can divide them. JLabel must able to wrap the content.

Comment: Just don't call `setSize()` (nor `setPreferredSize()`)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet could you write an answer to the question where you elaborate this some more? I am very interested!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of your `JLabel` is determined by the `LayoutManager` of the parent container. Consult [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more information.

Note that the `JLabel` has already the behavior you are looking for

1. When the text is too long, the text which is cut-off will be replaced by "..." . So in your example, the "Verylonglabel" would be replaced by e.g. "Verylo..."
2. You can use the `setToolTipText` method to specify the tooltip, which will be shown when hovering over the `JLabel`

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i have a question though: You say "1. When the text is too long, ..", but what decides when it is too long? Where do i set this value? I am now using MigLayout btw.

Comment: @Goatcat your `LayoutManager` decides this. Your `JLabel` decides what its preferred size is based on the text. However, it depends on the `LayoutManager` whether it respects that preferred size or not

Answer (score 3):

**This is what you need:**

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Verylonglabel");

// Create tool tip.
label.setToolTipText(label2.getText());

// Set the size of the label
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,40));// Width, Height
```

Comment: Some people say that you should avoid `.setPreferredSize()`. What do you have to say on the subject? When is it safe to use, and when should it be avoided?

Comment: You should generally avoid using setPreferredSize because your GUI component won't change size when the window changes size, like when the user maximizes the window.

Comment: @Robin and Gilbert Le Blanc, thank you both very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`setMaximumSize` will only be effective if the `LayoutManager` you use honors components' desired/max sizes.  You may want to check out `BoxLayout` as a `LayoutManager`.  Unlike several other Swing LayoutManagers, `BoxLayout` honors the size settings of its components.

This still leaves you the question of what size to set as the maximum size.  The width will be whatever you are targeting as your fixed value, but the height should be big enough for whatever font is being used.  Here is the code I would use to make the height flexible but the width fixed to 50 pixels:

```
label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10000, 50));
```

Finally, the tooltip will show the full label text with a line like:

```
label.setToolTipText(labelText);
```

Comment: The code here leaves the *width* flexible within a certain range but fixes the *height* to 50 pixels. I would change the example to the following:

`label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, Integer.MAX_VALUE));`